# Diophantine-like approximation of dynamical subsystems

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, examples, diophantine-approximation

For $\alpha\in [0,1)$ irrational we know that there exists a sequences $\{ q_n \}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $\{ p_n \}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$ \Big\vert \alpha-\frac{p_n}{q_n} \Big\vert \leq \frac{1}{q_n^2} \quad \text{and} \quad q_n\to \infty. $$

If I define for all $\beta\in[0,1)$ a dynamical system on $X=[0,1)$ via the map

$$ T_{\beta}:X\to X, \quad T_{\beta}(x)= x+\beta\;  (mod \; 1), $$

I can alternatively write this as

$$ d(\alpha, Orb_{\frac{1}{q_n}}(0))\leq \frac{1}{\vert Orb_{\frac{1}{q_n}}(0)\vert^2 } \quad \text{with} \quad Orb_{\frac{1}{q_n}}(0):=\Big\{ T_{\frac{1}{q_n}}^{m}(0): m\in \mathbb{Z} \Big\}.  $$

I was wondering whether there are examples of dynamical systems satisfying a similar flavor of approximation. More precisely, given a metric space $(X,d)$ and a homeomorphism $T:X\to X$, I consider $(X,T)$ as a dynamical system and its closed subsystem. I also denote $Orb_T(x):=\{ T^m(x): m\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ for any $x\in X$.

I'm interested  to find an $x_\infty\in X$ such that $\vert Orb_T(x_\infty)\vert=\infty$, but there exists a sequence $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq X$ satisfying
$\vert Orb_T(x_n)\vert:=q_n<\infty$ and $d\big( x_\infty, Orb_T(x_n)  \big)=O(q_n^{-\alpha})$, for some $\alpha >1$.

I would like to know whether there are any known systems with this diophantine-like approximation property. I tried looking at subshifts of the Bernoulli shift $A^\mathbb{Z}$, but I have found none so far. This seems like a somewhat analogous notion, so I was wondering whether this notion makes sense and actually occurs for some systems.